# What is "String toString() { .. }"?

Tags: groovy

So can you please help me to understand what `String toString() { "$email" }` will do in the following program???

```
class User  
{        
    Long id          
    Long version    

    String email   
    String password     

    String toString()
    { "$email" }

    def constraints = 
    {  
    email(email:true)  
    password(blank:false, password:true)     
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that whatever is in the `email` variable will be returned when `toString()` is called.

It could also be written as:

```
@Override
String toString() { 
  email 
}
```

but the writer decided to be "smart" (yes, I'm being sarcastic!) and use the [$ notation](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Special-character-handling-using-SimpleTemplate-td354719.html) of embedding a variable into a string.

*Remark*:
In groovy you don't have to use `return` - the default behavior is that the last statement inside a method will be returned.

Comment: I guess from the quotation marks you don't really think the use of the $ notation is smart? It's not, it's pointless, and your syntax should be preferred

Comment: It should be written the way you mentioned.

Comment: @Dónal agreed. I prefer the Java-style indentation too, the reason I left it "as is" was to make the differences easier to spot, but I guess that showing the right-way to indent is better. Thanks!

Comment: @alfasin no problem, my own preference is to also add `@Override`

Comment: @Dónal agreed again (can't really argue when you're right... :)